# request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() returns true after invalidating the session

Tags: session, servlets, invalidation

When I'm logging out the user, I'm invalidating his session by calling session.invalidate() and redirecting myself back to the login page.

Each and every page other than the login page in my application is a JSP page. What I'm checking in every JSP page is if the requested session exists and if the requested session ID is valid.

After logging out the user and calling session.invalidate(), if I try to directly open the url of my home page, it still returns request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() as true. Also, calling session.invalidate() does not make the session null.

The following is my code:

Logout.java

```
       session.inValidate();
```

In my home.jsp. I am explicitly checking if the requested session is valid.
The following is the code:

```
         HttpSession session=request.getSession();
         boolean a=request.isRequestedSessionValid()
         if(session==null || a==false){
         ...
         ...
         }
```

Trouble is session does not return null and a is still true, even after logging out the user( invalidating the session ).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without the respective code, we cannot help you. Also, please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> I'm invalidating his session by calling session.invalidate() ***and redirecting myself back to the login page.***

If the client makes a new request after its session is invalidated then the webapp will handle that request in the context of a new, initially valid session.  If the webapp sends a response to the client between the session invalidation and the new request, including, but not limited to, a redirect response, then that new request is unlikely to request the invalidated session's ID.  That's because whatever the means by which session association is maintained, the response gives the webapp an opportunity to communicate the end of the previous session to the client, if it even needs to do so at all.

The client might or might not request any session ID at all in that case.  If it does not, then you will see `request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` returning `false`; otherwise, the main scenario in which you will see `request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` returning `false` is when the session has timed out since the most recent response.  You cannot rely on this to determine whether the user has authenticated.

> After logging out the user and calling session.invalidate(), if I try to directly open the url of my home page, it still returns request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() as true.

Why should it not?

> Also, calling session.invalidate() does not make the session null.

No, it doesn't, nor should it.  If you want to be able to detect whether the session has been invalidated then you can make use of the fact that after it is invalidated, most of its methods will throw `IllegalStateException`.  But if you find yourself needing to know that -- other than by catching and handling the `IllegalStateException` in an appropriate context -- then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response John. So basically what I want to do is logout the user. So for that, I am invalidating the session. Is their any better way than this? Also as each of my pages are JSPs. So in each page , I am checking is the session associated with the request valid and if not I am showing the login page.
So, this is for stuff like.
Suppose you logout of facebook.com and then type facebook.com/home
(just an example)
It will show u the login page.
Is my approach bad?

Comment: Invalidating the session when you log out the user is absolutely standard.  If you want to be able to determine whether the user has logged in, then successfully logging in should modify the session in a way that so indicates.  One typical mechanism is to attach an attribute to the session -- often an object describing the logged-in user.  If you're using JAAS for security then you might not even need to do that: `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()` might then be enough.

Comment: I am not using JAAS, will take a look at that. Thanks. So, it has to be some kind of hack? u mean attaching something to session.

Comment: @IndraneelBende, attaching an attribute to the session is no hack; it's practically what the session is there for.  Among other things, it's how your JSPs track session-scoped variables.  Supposing that you want the session to carry information about the logged-in user for your JSPs' and servlets' use, having the login process attach that information is natural, as, therefore, is having other pages redirect the user to log in if that information is not attached.

Comment: appreciate ur comments! Thank you!